# contains() of Collection framework doesn't use hashcode, rather uses equals(), why?

Tags: java, collections

I was checking code of contains() method of Collection and could not find hashcode() usage. Here is the link of [contains() method javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)

Comment: Why would you expect hashcode to be used?  Two unequal objects could coincidentally have the same hashcode, but with regard to set theory, they should both be allowed to occupy the same set.

Comment: Due to agreement of hashcode and equals method, i expect hashcode to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why no optimisation on ArrayList or LinkedList implementation?

Because it is not necessarily an optimization.

It is only an optimization to call `hashCode` before `equals` if `hashCode` is significantly cheaper than `equals`.  If you knew that the object's implementation of `hashCode` caches the hash code value AND that you had previously called `hashCode` on the object, then it *could* be faster to call `hashCode` first.  But if either of those was not true, then you are likely to find that:

- the `hashCode` call is at least as expensive as the `equals` call  (after all, `hashCode` cannot "short circuit" like a well-implemented `equals` often can), and
- when the hash code values are equal, you still need to call `equals`.

The analysis gets very complicated ... but suffice it to say that in a lot of cases (considering all implementations of hashcode and equals, distributions of equal versus unequal elements, etc) using `hashCode` would be an ANTI-optimization.

Having said that, if you have a use-case where it would improve things to use `hashCode` as an optimization, you are free to implement your own custom collection classes.  Alternatively, you could optimize the element classes `equals` and `hashCode` methods so that `equals` itself checks a (cached) hash value.

Comment: Thanks for a very compelling answer but if i have a very complicated equals method which is expensive. Then i guess hashcode can be very useful. But i guess Collection framework violates agreement between hashcode and equals method.

Comment: 1) If `equals` is complicated, then `hashCode` probably has to be complicated as well  .... or else you will get lots of hash collisions.  2) *"Collection framework violates agreement between hashcode and equals method."*.  Actually, it doesn't.  It is not using `hashCode` at all ... so the contract is moot.

Answer (score 1):

The reason ArrayList does not need to use the **hashCode()** method because the ordering is determined by the insertion order. 
The hashCode() method is for objects in a **HashSet** or objects that are used as keys in a **HashMap**.

Comment: Hashcode is a guess whether two references are pointing to the same object or not, which is confirmed by equals method. So why hashcode is not used to guess so... Later equals can test the state of objects.

Comment: Firstly, Hascode is NOT a guess whether two references are pointing to the same object or not. Secondly, what is actually meant by "test the state of objects"?

Comment: Equals test the state of objects.... Hashcode is the guess... You get an integer value for an object which comes with some calculations. Same integer can come with other object as well. So its a guess that, references can point to same object.

Comment: So, you need to frame your statement properly, its not that Hashcode determines "_whether two references are pointing to the same object or not_". 
In brief, hash code is used to find the corresponding memory bucket of the object (This same bucket have other objects as well). In order to find the exact object in that bucket equals() is used.

Comment: In summary, hashcode is required prior to checking equality for those collection where hashing is used.
1. Locate the bucket. 2. Find exact object using equals.
    
In Arraylist we are checking only the equality of the objects because there is no concept of Hashing/bucket.


Please go through the Wikipedia 
[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)

Comment: Not only in hash collections, everywhere we should have hashcode-equals agreement. But just because hashcode is as expensive as equals, Java team checked state of Object in ArrayList, etc.

Comment: Ideally, Yes. We should always follow the hashcode-equals agreement.

Answer (score 0):

hash codes are just optimizations. Eventually, a `Collection#contains` or `Map#get` call must call `equals` to check that the passed object is really there, and not another object that happens to have the same hash code. If you look at specific implementations like `HashSet` or `HashMap`, you'll see that `hashCode()` is used along the way as an optimization.

Comment: Yes. Agreed on hash collections but in ArrayList implementation, you wont see hashcode.

Comment: Why no optimisation on ArrayList or q

Comment: Why no optimisation on ArrayList or LinkedList implementation?